# Email server do not accept emails sent by PHPmailer. I need email to look like it wasn't sent by PHPmailer. Is that possible?

Tags: phpmailer

First of all, I am not using this for spam or something like that. I am having my local XAMPP server running and PHPmailer set to generate and send and email to one particular recipient. I am using gmail smtp to send email.

If I use PHPmailer, email is immediately refused and in a second I will receive a "permanently failed delivery to following recipient.." email without any error.

If I sent exactly the same email manually and directly logged into gmail account, it will get delivered without a single problem.

I assume that recipients email server somehow recognizes that email wasn't sent directly from gmail account, but via PHPmailer, identifies it as "mail sent by machine" and therefore refuses it.

Is there a way how to set PHPmailer so recipient mail server won't be able to find out if mail was sent from original gmail account manually or not?

```
Return-Path: <XXXfwoc@gmail.com>
Received: from XXXsciante-PC (adsl-dyn117.78-98-63.t-com.sk. [78.98.63.117])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id g11sm7844695wjr.25.2015.05.16.08.48.59
        for <XXXqbn6spa7o6@tumblr.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 16 May 2015 08:49:35 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sat, 16 May 2015 15:48:57 +0000
To: XXXqbn6spa7o6@tumblr.com
From: XXXfwoc@gmail.com
Subject: XXX
Message-ID: <5c43cd065aa873fd86340feaecbf1764@XXXsciante-PC>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="b1_5c43cd065aa873fd86340feaecbf1764"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--b1_5c43cd065aa873fd86340feaecbf1764
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

email text here


--b1_5c43cd065aa873fd86340feaecbf1764
Content-Type: image/gif; name="XXX.gif"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="XXX.gif"

R0lGODlhQgHXAOcAAAAAAAAAQAAAgAAA/wAgAAAgQAAggAAg/wBAAABAQABAgABA/wBgAABgQABg
gABg/wCAAACAQACAgACA/wCgAACgQACggACg/wDAAADAQADAgADA/wD/AAD/QAD/gAD//yAAACAA
```

Comment: You need to post your code and the transcript of your output (SMTPDebug = 2) in order to get a sensible answer.

Comment: I have added header of message sent by gmail as remote server. I do not receive any useful debug information on local, because problem is not between local and smtp.gmail.com but between smtp.gmail.com and receiving tumblr email server. It worked for me in past, but recently they have increased some antispam security or something.

Comment: Well, the structure looks fine, but you can suppress the PHPMailer `X-Mailer` header by doing `$mail->XMailer = ' ';` You must leave a space in there to suppress the header.

Comment: Thanks! I have supressed that line successfully! But, mail was still refused. Is there any way how to override message id? I mean to replace @XXXciante-PC with @mail.gmail.com? Maybe server takes that into account.

Comment: You can set the message ID with `$mail->MessageID = 'whatever';`. Also upgrade to PHPMailer 5.2.10 as it has some MIME structure fixes. Overall this is a little mysterious - PHPMailer messages are pretty vanilla - so I'd perhaps look at other factors.

Comment: Nah, i set messageID to replace my local pc computer name by mail.gmail.com but it didnt help. But i have noticed one more thing, if I add small jpeg attachment it email is accepted, if I add little big bigger gif attachment it gets refused. But note here, that if i send same attachment manually from gmail account it gets trough. So maybe it has something to do with attachment. I have to upgrade PHPmailer as you suggest, plus i will test different sizes and file types as attachments.